# How to write loop through a folder of CSV and add one column to each and populate it

Tags: r, csv

I have more than 1400 csv in Matrix format, and I would like to add the mean of the lower or upper triangle of each matrix to the csv table.

Now I can get the mean of all the values the way I want, but I cannot add the value to the existing csv tables. Every time I try to `write.csv`, it only leaves one value and deletes all the existing fields.

```
file_list <- list.files(path=folder, pattern="*.csv")

dfList <- lapply(files, function(i) {
 df <- read.csv(i)
 df$mean <- gsub("mean", "", i) 
 return(df)
  })

 csvlist<-lapply(files,function(i)
 {(mean(as.numeric(sm2vec(subset(as.matrix(read.csv(i)),select = -
 Document)))))
  })

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){write.csv(file_list[j],file = 
file_list[i],append = TRUE)}
```

these were some of the things I tried.

Comment: You should add an example of intput csv file and how the final result should look like for this file

Comment: 'write.csv' writes R objects to .csv files, so just using the function with just value of your matrix triangle mean will only have the triangle mean in it. You would need to open the whole matrix and append the triangle mean and then write matrix to csv. You need 'append' argument.

Comment: What is *sm2vec*? Or *Document*? We need full reproducible examples.

Comment: I would be careful about how you use append. You will lose data if not used correctly. Check it first.